# How to use Navigation.InsertPageBefore in a ViewModel class in xamarin forms?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation

I was using the below code in my previous application to remove login page from the stack once the user has successfully logged in.

```
var supervisor = new Supervisor();

Navigation.InsertPageBefore(supervisor, this);

Navigation.PopAsync();

btnLogin.IsEnabled = true;

Spinner.IsEnabled = false;
```

I want to do the same in a viewmodel class where I am not able to use "this" keyword as it represents a page. So is there any other way in which I can accomplish my task.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: you can add a property ,use the current page to init it when you creat the ViewModel ,and you  can use this parameter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution for the problem, In MVVM where you have to make your Page as root page then just use

Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Supervisor());

This line will remove your login page from the stack and make the MasterDetail page(in this case Supervisor page) as your root page.

Hope this helps to someone.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your LoginPage doesn't change of place on the Stack, you could refer to it trought the Navigation Stack.

Let's say that your LoginPage is your MainPage (root) :

```
var supervisor = new Supervisor();
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(supervisor, Navigation.NavigationStack[0]);
Navigation.PopAsync();
```

So with the code above, you add your `supervisor` before the root of the Stack then pop the root.